# How to make my blackberry application downloadable?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have a simple "hello world" blackberry application. I want to put my compiled files (.jad,.jar or .cod) to my web server and let my application to be downloaded by my blackberry users.

I have tried to use .jad files for downloading. However when I click the button, the blackberry device displays the content of the .jad file line by line and nothing happens.

In short, I want to put a link on my page and when a user click it, my app will be downloaded his/her device.

How can I do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web server has to apply the appropriate MIME type to both the JAD and the COD files.

- JAD = text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor
- COD = application/vnd.rim.cod

See your web server documentation on how to specify MIME types for served files. Quite often you can do this with a .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem by adding a descriptor to the top of my jsp file.